# How to highlight and select text on mobile using JS

Tags: javascript, highlight, touchscreen

I wish to highlight text on touchscreens. From the selected text (yellow) there should appear a popup (green)
[image: highlight text in red box. Green box appears]

On desktop computers, using mouse, I can highlight and select text from the red box using functions `.on("mousedown")` and `.on("mouseup")`

```
  $("body").on("mousedown", ".redbox", async function(e) {
            DoSomething(e);               
    });
```

and

```
$("body").on("mouseup",".redbox", function(e) {
                
        
        if (this.innerHTML != "") {
            selectTextFromWindow(e);
        }
      

    });
```

However, I wish to do the same on mobile devices, and have not been succesful. I know it has something to do with touchevents, but since I am a copy-paste-kinda-guy and not a real developer, i have not been able to find a live example to copy from. Snippets are very much appreaciated!